# Changing Default Cursor Style to Custom Cursor

Tags: html, css

I am making an web application.
In my web application, I want to change the default cursor to Custom cursor.
For that i am applying following code in my XHTML Page in head element.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            cursor: url('images/normal.ani')
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <p> Hello World</p> 
</body>
```

Now, This code is working fine and changing the default cursor to my custom cursor  in Internet Explorer 7.0.
But the same code doesn't working in Mozilla Firefox (15.0.1) and Google Chrome(21.0).
Please Help me out ....
Thank u in advance

Comment: That's not [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#normative).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6982850/1354978

Comment: okay Sorry i forget to enclose HTML tag..but you can take this page as pure HTML page. In Html page also it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox requires a second non-url argument such as

```
 cursor: url('images/normal.ani'), auto;
```

There is a good reference at Quirksmode [CSS2 - Cursor Styles](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html)

Comment: Hi..I tried same thing but still it's not working and shows me only default cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that you are only able to use the file type .ani and animated cursors (.ani,.gif) in IE.

Page from the Mozilla developers about cursor urls

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property

Post here if your interested in a work around (quite ugly though)

http://ye5.blogspot.co.nz/2011/01/animated-mouse-cursor-on-mozilla.html

Comment: I have tried all the formats like .ani, .cur, .gif, .ico but still i am getting only default cursor.

Comment: I did a test myself, with the following code, 
        body{
            cursor: url('cursor/pointer.cur'), auto;
        }
and it worked fine in both chrome v 21 and firefox v 15. Definitely needed the ", auto" at the end though